# Letsencrypt add domain to existing certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am just simply trying to add the domain `test.example.com` to the certificate that already exists for `example.com`. How do I add a domain to my existing certificate and replace the old certificate?

I have tried these few commands

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --cert-path /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example.com --expand -d test.example.com

./letsencrypt-auto certonly -d example.com --expand -d test.example.com
```

Result: both created a brand new cert in a new folder test.example.com-0001

```
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --renew-by-default  --expand -d test.example.com
```

Result: error folder test.example.com already exists.

```
./letsencrypt-auto renew --expand -d orange.fidka.com
```

Result: error, I can only renew if my certificate is expired.

Comment: This question has been reopened on Super User: https://superuser.com/questions/1432541/letsencrypt-certbot-add-domain-to-existing-certificate

Comment: To anyone now viewing this question: I would recommend having a look at the [answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1432542/964192). It uses `certbot --expand` which is closer to what this question is asking imo

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You need to specify all of the names, including those already registered.

I used the following command originally to register some certificates:

```
/opt/certbot/certbot-auto certonly --webroot --agree-tos -w /srv/www/letsencrypt/ \
--email me@example.com \
--expand -d example.com,www.example.com
```

... and just now I successfully used the following command to expand my registration to include a new subdomain as a SAN:

```
/opt/certbot/certbot-auto certonly --webroot --agree-tos -w /srv/www/letsencrypt/ \
--expand -d example.com,www.example.com,click.example.com
```

From the [documentation](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#command-line-options):

> --expand "If an existing cert covers some subset of the requested names, always expand and replace it with the additional names."

Don't forget to restart the server to load the new certificates if you are running nginx.

Comment: The command changed slightly to `certbot-auto certonly -a webroot ...`

Comment: does it work for standalone plugin?

Comment: When I use the above, it creates a new cert on it's own, with a `-001` at the end.

Comment: Ran it on production, expand does not seem to require any visible down time. I used certbot-auto

Comment: @simon-hampel When the SSL Certificate is expanded, does it extend the expire date for all the domains that are defined in the list.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas - it's been a while since I had to do this, but I'm pretty sure it creates a brand new certificate, so you get the full 90 day expiry

Comment: didn't work for me. it made a completely new cert instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: Notice that there must be NO SPACE between domain1 comma and domain2: .... -d example.com,www.example.com

Answer (score 53):

**Apache on Ubuntu**, using the Apache plugin:

```
sudo certbot certonly --cert-name example.com -d m.example.com,www.m.example.com
```

The above command is vividly explained in the [Certbot user guide on changing a certificate's domain names](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#changing-a-certificate-s-domains). Note that the command for changing a certificate's domain names applies to adding new domain names as well.

**Edit**

If running the above command gives you the error message

> Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA.

follow [these instructions from the Let's Encrypt Community](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/solution-client-with-the-currently-selected-authenticator-does-not-support-any-combination-of-challenges-that-will-satisfy-the-ca/49983)

Comment: It is probably mentioned in the documentation but if you are just adding to existing you need to add the existing domain again - or it will be removed

Comment: they also have the `--expand` option that you initially think it allows you to add while keeping existent domains, but it doesn't do that (facepalm). I don't really like their options or documentation.

Answer (score 43):

This is how i registered my domain:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d mydomain.com
```

Then it was possible to use the same command with additional domains and follow the instructions:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d mydomain.com,x.mydomain.com,y.mydomain.com
```

Comment: i just replaced `letsencrypt` with `./certbot-auto` and it works! Command `./certbot-auto --nginx -d domain1.com,domain2.com` ask if i want to expand existing cert and does the job.

Comment: Thanks. It saves my time. I run `./letsencrypt-auto --debug -d new-domain.com -d new-alias.com`

Answer (score 5):

You can replace the certificate by just running the certbot again with `./certbot-auto certonly`

You will be prompted with this message if you try to generate a certificate for a domain that you have already covered by an existing certificate:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You have an existing certificate that contains a portion of the domains you
requested (ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/<domain>.conf)

It contains these names: <domain>

You requested these names for the new certificate: <domain>,
<the domain you want to add to the cert>.

Do you want to expand and replace this existing certificate with the new
certificate?
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just chose `Expand` and replace it.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to setup a SSL certificated for a domain AND multiple subdomains by using using `--cert-name` combined with `--expand` options.

See official certbot-auto documentation at https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html

Example:

```
certbot-auto certonly --cert-name mydomain.com.br \
--renew-by-default -a webroot -n --expand \
--webroot-path=/usr/share/nginx/html \
-d mydomain.com.br \
-d www.mydomain.com.br \
-d aaa1.com.br \
-d aaa2.com.br \
-d aaa3.com.br
```

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me

```
 sudo letsencrypt certonly -a webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html -d
 domain.com -d www.domain.com
```