# Simplest command to expand certificate

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am not using `certbot`, only `letsencrypt` command, and  [this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38302401/287948) is so complex to something so simple: use `--expand` in a `letsencrypt` command.

The question here: **how to use `--expand`, what the correct syntax?**  
[there are no example in the guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#command-line-options).

---

Supposing that *domain1* is the main domain, and *domain2* and *domain3* was created with the initial command, 
`letsencrypt --apache -d domanin1 -d www.domanin1 -d wiki.domanin1 -d domanin2 -d www.domanin2 -d domanin3`

... What the correct syntax to add a *domain4*? 1, 2 ... or 5?

1. `letsencrypt --apache --expand domanin4`
2. `letsencrypt --apache --expand -d domanin4`
3. `letsencrypt --expand -d domanin4`
4. `letsencrypt --apache --expand -d domanin1 -d domanin4`
5. `letsencrypt --apache --expand -d domanin1 -d www.domanin1 -d wiki.domanin1 -d domanin2 -d www.domanin2 -d domanin3 -d domain4`

PS: need to repeat all domains and subdomains in the expansion?

Answer (score 0):

This question will have no answer... Because `letsencrypt` is no longer developed (!), if you using: you using something junk.

> *certbot* is the more recent version of `letsencrypt` (there was a change of name)

([see  community.letsencrypt.org/24474](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/we-really-need-to-use-letsencrypt-command-better-certbot/24474/2))

So, the remain question is **"how to do an `--expand` equivalent with *certbot*?"**  Because:

> `--expand` is a *certbot* option that we haven't implemented/don't support. (...) However, we have a `--hooks` option which has similar functionality.

(see [letsencrypt-cli/issues](https://github.com/Daplie/letsencrypt-cli/issues/32#issuecomment-268382820))

So, as the question request, **simplest `certbot --hooks` command to expand certificate?**

PS: somebody [say that it is impossible!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/301322/130402)