# Simplest certbot command to expand a certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, certbot

In nowadays (...2017), what the simplest and secure `certbot` command to expand an existing certificate?

---

NOTES:

- [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324457/287948) is not about nowadays, `--expand` is not in use, etc.

Answer (score 3):

So far, 2017, [version 0.12](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases/tag/v0.12.0), no simple way.  The procedure is to do all certificate.... The command is simple,

```
 certbot --cert-name xxxx.com.family -d xxxx.com -d xxxx.org -d xxxx2.org
```

There are a Wishlist with it, at [certbot/issues/4352](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4352).

Comment: `--expand` add an additional domain is back in cerbot v0.10: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/4055 and https://github.com/certbot/certbot/pull/4053.

Comment: Thanks @almccann, good links. Yes, now we can expand (!), was a problem  in UBUNTU distribution... now `apt` use updated *certbot*. The [*issue #4352*](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/4352) is yet valid, for remove domains.

Comment: News?  See something using `certbot-auto` 
 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43750270/287948

Answer (score 1):

[See this official about Re-creating and Updating Existing Certificates](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#re-creating-and-updating-existing-certificates)